# Redirect to Virtual Folder with same site different languages in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, multilingual

I have requirement to redirect/load page by Geo locating the user and get the language set in CMS for that country and if User Geolocation is not found in CMS settings then load/redirect page to english(en) language.

```
  <site name="mysite" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
                  targetHostName="mysite.dev.local" 
                  database="web" 
                  virtualFolder="/en" 
                  physicalFolder="/en" 
                  language="en" 
                  rootPath="/sitecore/content/PAL" 
                  startItem="/Home" />
  <site name="mysiteTaiwan" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
                  targetHostName="mysite.dev.local" 
                  database="web" 
                  virtualFolder="/tw" 
                  physicalFolder="/tw" 
                  language="zh-TW" 
                  rootPath="/sitecore/content/PAL" 
                  startItem="/Home" />
```

Code:

```
  public class LanguageResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            // Eject for bypassed sites: e.g., sitecore shell, etc.
            if (Context.Site != null && MultiSiteSettings.SiteResolver.IgnoredSites.Contains(Context.Site.Name))
                return;
            // Eject if database or itempath are null/empty
            if (Context.Database == null || Context.PageMode.IsNormal == false || args.Url.ItemPath.Length == 0)
                return;

            var path = args.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

            // Eject for bypassed paths: e.g., /api/*, etc.
            var bypassedPathPrefixes = MultiSiteSettings.SiteResolver.IgnoredPrefixes;
            if (bypassedPathPrefixes.Any(s => path.StartsWith(s)))
                return;

            string sitepath = ExtractSitePath(path);
            var defaultLanguage = "en";
            string virtualfolder = $"/{defaultLanguage}";
            var userCountryCode = "GB";//NormalizeCountryForComparison(_masterDataService.GetCountryForVisit());
            
            var countriesLanguageSettings = _masterDataRepository.GetCountriesDefaultLanguageSettings(Context.Language);
            bool countryFound = false;
            foreach (var country in countriesLanguageSettings.Countries)
            {
                var compareCountry = NormalizeCountryForComparison(country.CountryCode);
                if (compareCountry == userCountryCode ||
                    compareCountry.Contains(userCountryCode) ||
                    userCountryCode.Contains(compareCountry))
                {
                    countryFound = true;
                    defaultLanguage = country.RegionalIsoCode;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (countryFound && defaultLanguage != null)
            {
                virtualfolder = $"/{defaultLanguage}/{userCountryCode}/";
            }
            args.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(virtualfolder, true);
        }
    }



   public class ResolveURL : ItemUrlBuilder
    {
        public override string Build(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {

            // Eject for bypassed sites: e.g., sitecore shell, etc.
            if (Context.Site != null && MultiSiteSettings.SiteResolver.IgnoredSites.Contains(Context.Site.Name))
            {
                return base.Build(item, options);
            }
            var defaultLanguage = "en";
            var userCountryCode = "GB"; //NormalizeCountryForComparison(_masterDataService.GetCountryForVisit());
            var countriesLanguageSettings = _masterDataRepository.GetCountriesDefaultLanguageSettings(Context.Language);
            bool countryFound = false;
            foreach (var country in countriesLanguageSettings.Countries)
            {
                var compareCountry = NormalizeCountryForComparison(country.CountryCode);
                if (compareCountry == userCountryCode ||
                    compareCountry.Contains(userCountryCode) ||
                    userCountryCode.Contains(compareCountry))
                {
                    defaultLanguage = country.RegionalIsoCode;
                    countryFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //options.LanguageEmbedding = Sitecore.Links.LanguageEmbedding.Always;
            var itemUrl = base.Build(item, options);
            if (countryFound && (Context.Language.ToString().Contains(defaultLanguage) || Context.Language.ToString().ToLower() == defaultLanguage.ToLower()))
            {
                var newLangCode = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", Context.Language, userCountryCode.ToLower());

                itemUrl = base.Build(item, options).Replace(Context.Language.ToString().ToLower(), newLangCode);

                return itemUrl;
            }
    }
```

Am getting "The requested document was not found" page, please let me know what am i missing.
Also please let me know if i can achieve my requirement in any other way.